# SFTP using Ciphers and Key Exchange

Tags: sftp, ssis, cipher

Previously I was gaining access and transferring files (SSIS execute process task) with a .txt file configured as:

```
option batch on
option confirm off
open sftp://Username:password@hostsite.com:22  -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2222 00:00:00:00:00:0c:00:ee:e0:00:0d:0e:b0:0a:00:00"
option transfer binary
Put -nopermissions -resumesupport=Off   -nopreservetime E:\path.txt /Inbound/path/
```

Now I'm told to use a new SFTP structure – site name: hostname.com and IP address 100.00.000.000.

I'm provided a list of ciphers and key exchanges for example: ECDHE-RSA-AES000-GCM-SHA000  (Key Exchange=ECDH; Auth=RSA)  (I've changed some characters for security reasons)

How do I change the .txt file to use this new way?

Comment: Are you sure the new site is supposed to use SFTP and not FTPS? Huge difference.

Comment: This was in the notes: In the interest of using only the most secure ciphers available, the new SFTP server will exclusively support the following cipher suites:

Comment: Sounds like whoever wrote the notes got a few things mixed up... the problem is that 'cipher suites' are a TLS thing (FTPS uses the same TLS that powers HTTPS) and they just outright don't apply to SFTP (which is SSH-based). And in any case, there are _no_ security reasons to censor their names.

Comment: Thank you for this.  And yes after Googling I see that ciphers don't need to masked for security purposes.  I've reached out to folks in my org to get this resolved.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented by @Kim, `ECDHE-RSA-AES***-GCM-SHA***` is a TLS/SSL cipher suite. TLS/SSL is used by FTP(S). While SFTP uses SSH.

Your script file looks like [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) supports both SFTP and FTP(S).

Just change your [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) to use [`ftpes://`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url#elements) instead of `sftp://`. Additionally, the port number will differ, but let's assume that your FTP(S) server uses the standard port. Also `-hostkey` is not relevant for FTPS.

```
open ftpes://username:password@example.com/
```

The rest of the script might stay the same. Though it's possible that the remote path (`/Inbound/path/`) might need an update too.

---

Note that contrary to SFTP, the FTP is supported natively by SSIS. So you might use the native SSIS FTP task as well. But that's a larger change, than the simple WinSCP script update.

Comment: Thank you Martin.  Tried open ftpes://  and I get message ftpes does not exist.  Once the  remote server's IP address was whitelisted and I updated Winscp I'm able to log onto the remote server via Winscp's UI.  But still not able to automate with a script

Comment: When I leave it as Open sftp I get the message: Disconnected: Server protocol violation: unexpected SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED packet

Comment: What version of WinSCP are you using?

Comment: Ok I changed it to ftps and it seemed to connect, then get different message: Negotiating TLS Connection Connection failed Disconnected

Comment: getting version now

Comment: Version 5.5.5 I believe.  Updated to latest version this morning

Comment: Now says can't establish TLS connection

Comment: Exact error message please + Ideally a full session log file. + Session log file from UI for comparison would help too.

Comment: So I'm looking where I can upload a .txt file of the error log.  When I put in box...too many characters

Comment: *****WARNING**********
. 2020-04-23 15:21:48.851 Keyboard-interactive authentication failed
! 2020-04-23 15:21:48.851 Access denied
. 2020-04-23 15:21:48.859 Server offered these authentication methods: password,keyboard-interactive
. 2020-04-23 15:21:48.859 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2020-04-23 15:21:48.883 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, "Enter password: ")
. 2020-04-23 15:21:55.735 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
. 2020-04-23 15:21:55.735 Closing connection.
* 2020-04-23 15:21:55.771 (ESshFatal)

Comment: So even though the password is in the script I got this message.  Also using the UI I enter the password, but it asks me again,then it connects

Comment: You can upload the log to https://pastebin.com/ and post a link here - The log snippet you have posted is for SFTP, not FTP(ES).

Comment: FTPS Script and Error Log has been Pasted

Comment: Pasted where? There is the link?

Answer (score 1):

So the updated version of WinSCP was 5.17.5. The server's IP address I was transferring the files from was added to the receiving server's whitelist. Then I could connect to the receiving server via WinSCP's UI by entering *Host name*, *username/password* (port 22 in my case). In *Advanced settings* *Directories* I added the path, in *SSH/Key Exchange* I ensured *ECDH* key exchange was at the top of the list and *RSA* based was 2nd. Login was successful. Then I went to the *Session* tab - *Generate URL/Code*, checked include the *SSH host key* (if not greyed out) then went to the *Script* tab and it will give you the initial `open` command that it is using during that session. It will give you the SHA-256 fingerprint of the host key instead of the MD5 we’ve been used to using.  Copy to the clipboard, I then used this as the Open line in my script: Example:

```
Option batch On
Option confirm Off

open sftp://Username:password@hostsite.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 k8L86hrEaiZI+v/fxxxxx/Igxxxxxxx/iF1iKzI=" -rawsettings KEX="ecdh,rsa,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,WARN,dh-group1-sha1"

# Your command 1
# Your command 2
Close
exit
```

Now my script executes and transfers the file.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your problem. But note that you have asked about `ECDHE-RSA-AES000-GCM-SHA000`, what looks like TLS ciphersuite. While your solution uses SFTP, what has nothing to do with TLS. You have something wrong in your requirements.